Displaying lookup field selected record's one of the field value on vf page
I am trying to display field value of Product Type from selected record on Vf page.
The problem is the product type value is not displaying on vf page.
Note: I have tried inputfield, outputfield, outputtext tags but same result no change.
Please refer the code and screenshot

<apex:outputPanel id="complaintQuestions">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Questions" id="complaintQs" columns="1" rendered="{!nonMigratedFlagChecked}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.NonMigratedPolicyNumber__c}" required="true" style="width: 300px" />
        
        <!-- Product Name Lookup Field -->
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.ProductName__c}" id="productName" onchange="updateProductType();"/>
        
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.ExternalTrustee__c}" style="width: 300px"/> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.NonMigratedClaimRef__c}" style="width: 300px"/>
        
        <!-- Output Text for Product Type -->
        <apex:outputText value="{!ProductType}" label="Product Type" style="width: 300px" id="productType"/>
        
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.Catastrophe_Event__c}" id="catastropheEvent" onclick="lineOfBusiness();"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!theCase.Catastrophe_Event_Details__c}" id="catastropheEventDetail" style="width: 300px"/>
        
        <!-- Action Function to Recalculate Product Type -->
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:actionFunction name="updateProductType" action="{!fetchProductType}" rerender="productType"/>
</apex:outputPanel>

public void fetchProductType() {

if (theCase.ProductName__c != null){

Product_Directory__c product =[SELECT Product_Type__c FROM Product_Directory__c WHERE Product_Name__c =: theCase.Product_Name__c LIMIT 1];

ProductType = product.Product_Type__c;

} else {

ProductType = null;

}
}


Does VF controller property ProductType look like public String ProductType {get; private set;} ?

Yes @cropredy, I have already included these in my controller, even though it was not displaying.

in debug, does the method fetchProductType() get invoked and executes the query on Product_Directory__c?

@cropredy, the method is working and it is calling when ever the field value changes. But only after remaining all the required field values are given. Then if we change the field value it was working as expected.
